# Java, basic array error

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to do a Java program that will let me input 10 words, and then the words should be repeated in reverse order (the last first etc).

This is my current code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

public class Words {

public static void main(String[] args){

String word[] = {};

for(int x = 0; x < 10; x+=1) {

System.out.println("Input any word");

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
word = new String[] { input.next() };

      }

for(int y = 9; y >= 0; y-=1) {

System.out.println(word[y]);

      }
}}
```

It gives me the following error when trying to compile:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9 at Words.main(Words.java:21)

I am new to Java and would appreciate help, thanks in advice.

Comment: `word` is only getting initialized with 1 String (scanner.next()). You are then looping through and trying to print up to 9 values from the array, 8 of which don't exist. `word`'s length is 1, which only allows index [0], yet you're trting to access indexes [1] through [8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how arrays work.
Change `String word[] = {};` to `String word[] = new String[10];`

Also, change `word = new String[] { input.next() };` to `word[x] = input.next()`.

It is also a good idea to move `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` outside of the `for` loop. You should read up on how arrays work to make sure this doesn't happen again.

Comment: If the task is to print the words out in reverse order,  then reading about Stacks might be intetrsting as well.

Comment: Yes, but you need to walk before you can run(To use a metaphor)

Answer (score 0):

You could try use an ArrayList to do this like so:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        do{
            System.out.println("Enter word");
            String word = sc.nextLine();
            al.add(word);
            if(al.size()==10){
                System.out.println("Words in reverse order");           
                for(int i = al.size()-1; i>= 0; i--){
                    System.out.println(al.get(i));
                }
            }
        }while(al.size()<10);
    }
}
```

I think this answers your question properly.

All the best

Sean